# How to add own style to sorted column in ng-grid

Tags: ng-grid

My ng-grid's one column is sorted. I want to add green color in the background of that column only.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: $scope.gridOpts = {
            
            headerRowHeight : 40,
            rowHeight : 40,
     sortInfo:{
                fields:['name'], directions:['desc']
            },
            columnDefs : [{
                field : 'name',
                displayName : 'Name'
            }],

            multiSelect : false,
            sortable: true,
            keepLastSelected:false,
            showContextMenu : true
        };

Comment: This is an simple grid with one sorted column. I want to add green color in background of sorted column